# Newbie with Node JS how to set and get a cookie

Tags: node.js

I am a newbie with nodejs coming from python.

Below is my standard script for setting and getting cookies in tornado.

```
if not self.get_cookie('mdi'):
            self.cookie_id=str(uuid4())
            self.set_cookie('mdi', self.cookie_id, domain='mdi.com',expires_days=365*2)
        else:
            self.cookie_id = self.get_cookie('mdi')
```

What would be the equivalent in NodeJS.  I use uuid4 to create cookie id's in python.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using something like expressjs in node?

Comment: I am new, started today...lol..I have to google expressjs

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a Web framework for node, such as [Express](http://expressjs.com/) (but there are [others](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-web-frameworks-full)).

Express offers cookie functionality with [`res.cookie`](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#res.cookie%28%29). You can do stuff like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.cookie('rememberme', 'yes',
             { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 900000), httpOnly: true });
});
```

Then you can read it back like this:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.cookies.rememberme);
});
```

Finally, you can clear it with:

```
res.clearCookie('rememberme');
```